# MonacaアプリでFaceBook認証を使ったログイン実装

Tags: monaca, facebook

こんにちわ。
Monacaでアプリ開発を行っております。

FaceBookアカウントを持っている場合、その情報を使って
アプリにログインできるようにしたいのですが、それは技術的に可能なのでしょうか？

一通り調べて、開発者アカウント開設やアプリID等は用意できました。
しかし、IDやトークン取得の為のFacebook公式SDKが、Monacaでは動かない
（アプリにurlがない為）らしく、情報が取得できていない状態です。

ちなみにユーザ情報等は外部レンタルサーバ（MySQL）に保存しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

可能です。
方法は私の知る限り2種類あります。

ひとつはfacebook SDK for javascriptを使用する方法です。
こちらに関しては私はやった事はありませんが、Monacaの会社の公式ブログで紹介されています。
http://blog.asial.co.jp/1432

もうひとつはアプリ内でinappbrowserを起動して、外部レンタルサーバー上で認証を行う方法です。
私の場合はPHPで認証を行いました。

具体的な方法としましては、inappbrowserを立ち上げる前にユニークなトークンを生成して、ajaxで外部サーバーのMySQLに保存します。
そのトークンをinappbrowserで開くURLのGET値につけます。
開いた外部サーバ上でPHPのFacebook認証を行い、認証が完了すれば取得したFacebookの情報とトークンをMySQLに保存します。
ここまでの処理が完了すればinappbrowserを閉じさせます。
閉じさせる方法としては、そのサイト上で「認証が完了しました、このブラウザを閉じてアプリに戻ってください」のテキストを表示させるか、強制的に特定のURLに飛ばして以下の方法で「特定のURLに移動した時にinappbrowserを閉じる」事ができます。

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('認証先のURL', '_blank', 'location=yes');
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
    if(event.url == "認証が終わった後に強制的に飛ばすURL"){
      ref.close(); #閉じる
    }
});
```

そしてinappbrowserには閉じたときに発生するイベントがありますので、ajaxでMySQLにトークンとFacebookの情報が存在するか確認します。
[inappbrowserのイベントに関する情報](https://docs.monaca.io/ja/reference/cordova_6.2/inappbrowser/)

この方法は少し回りくどい気もしますが、私は元々アプリではなくWEBサイトでPHPのFacebook認証を利用していたので、こちらを採用しています。

Comment: とても丁寧に回答して頂き、ありがとうございます。可能である事を知り、ひとまず安心いたしました。まずはどちらも試してみたいと思います。　ご回答頂きありがとうございました！

Comment: すみません、追加でお聞きしたいことが御座います。教えて頂いたやり方の内、phpを利用して認証を行った場合、認証時にFacebookのメールアドレスやパスワードの入力は必要になりますか？個人的には、FB公式アプリ等で既にログイン済の場合は、いちいち情報を入力しなくても、ワンタッチでログインできるようにしたいと考えいています。（LINEのアプリがそうだったので）

Comment: 上記の方法では実現できません。LINEはネイティブの言語を使ってアプリを作成しています。なのでFacebookが用意しているネイティブ言語用のSDKを使うことによってその動作を実現させています。ハイブリッドアプリでネイティブ言語用のSDKを使うにはこちらのプラグイン https://www.npmjs.com/package/aerogear-cordova-oauth2 を利用する必要がありますが、MonacaではMonaca指定のプラグイン以外を使うのは有料プランに移行する必要があります。

Comment: ご回答頂き有難うございます。やはりできないのですね・・・後々有償プランに乗り換えようと考えていますので、乗換後に教えて頂いたプラグインを試してみます。ずっと詰まっていた部分だったので、非常に助かりました、ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0):

こちらのhttps://npmjs.com/package/aerogear-cordova-oauth2ですが、monacaで実装できた方いらっしゃいますか？cordovaでは実装可能かもしれませんが、当方のmonaca環境ではエラーが発生しビルドできません。
他のcordova-plugin-facebook4などもmonacaのandroidsdkバージョンが対応していないためできず、monacaでFacebook公式アプリ経由でのログインができるプラグインは現状無いかと思われます。